# Make a Visual Studio command button hide when in debug mode

Tags: visual-studio-2010, add-in, visual-studio-extensions

I'm creating an extension for Visual Studio 2010.
The extension is made available to the user via a button in the Debug-menu of VS.

The button is defined as follows in the VSCT file:

```
<Button guid="guidRTKDebuggerCmdSet" id="cmdidRtkDebug" priority="0x0300" type="Button">
<Parent guid="guidVSDebugGroup" id="IDG_EXECUTION" />
<Icon guid="guidImages" id="bmpPic1" />
    <CommandFlag>DefaultInvisible</CommandFlag>
    <CommandFlag>DynamicVisibility</CommandFlag>
<Strings>
    <CommandName>cmdidRtkDebug</CommandName>
    <ButtonText>My Debug Extension</ButtonText>
</Strings>
</Button>
```

How would I make the button disappear when the debugger starts? All other debug buttons in Visual Studio show exactly this behavior, but my button remains visible all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use VisibilityConstraints (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166229.aspx) and list all needed contexts except UICONTEXT_Debugging (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vsconstants.aspx).

```
<VisibilityConstraints>
  <VisibilityItem guid="guidRTKDebuggerCmdSet"        id="cmdidRtkDebug"
    context="UICONTEXT_SolutionHasSingleProject" />
  <VisibilityItem guid="guidRTKDebuggerCmdSet"        id="cmdidRtkDebug"
    context="UICONTEXT_SolutionHasMultipleProjects" />
</VisibilityConstraints>
```